# scala recursive loop with future results

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a function in my controller like this:

```
 def getPreviousVersions(id: Int): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
    val result: Future[Option[ElementModel]] =  dto.getPreviousVersion(id)

    // while-loop or whatever is best practice
    // val arrayOfElements: Future[Seq[ElementModel] = ...

    val c = for {
      previousVersions <- arrayOfElements
    } yield previousVersions 

    //do something with the versions
    //Return something in the end
  }
```

My model looks like this:

```
case class ElementModel(
                                  ...
                                  previousVersion: Option[Int],
                                  ...)
```

I store the id of the latest previousVersion in my model. Now, what I want to do is iterate either recursively or with a while-loop or whatever is best-practice to get the previousVersion of the previousVersion and so on. 
The idea is to get all previous versions, store them in a sequence and pass this `seq` to another function.

Is there a smooth, proper way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def getVersionSequence(id: Int): Future[List[ElementModel]] = {

  def _getVersionSequence(id: Int, fList: Future[List[ElementModel]]): Future[List[ElementModel]] = {
    dto.getPreviousVersion(id).flatMap({
      case Some(elementModel) => elementModel.previousVersion match {
        case Some(pVId) => _getVersionSequence(pVId, fList.map(list => elementModel +: list))
        case None => fList.map(list => elementModel +: list)
      }
      case None => fList
    })
  }

  val fInvertedList = _getVersionSequence(id, Future(List.empty[ElementModel]))

  fInvertedList.map(list => list.reverse)
}


def getPreviousVersions(id: Int): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
  val c: Future[List[ElementModel]] = getVersionSequence(id)

  //do something with the versions
  //Return something in the end
}
```

Comment: This looks quite promising. However when I do this:
 getVersionSequence(id).map { elements =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(elements ))
    }
It returns an array with a single object, although this object has an attribute "previousVersion." So I expected there to be 2 objects within the array. As many objects as "previousVersion" isn't none/null.

Comment: Are you sure that the `previousVersion` chain is correct ? Are you also counting the currentVersion... as this function will only return previousVersions of the id provided ?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine. I made a mistake in my sql statement where I ask for another attribute to be true. Sorry and a huge thank you!

Comment: Just a small correction: It should be:   `_getVersionSequence(elementModel.id.get, fList.map(list => elementModel +: list))`. Otherwise it skips an element.

Answer (score 1):

```
 def getPreviousVersion(previousVersionId: Int): Future[ElementModel] = dto.getElementModelForId(previousVersionId)
/*This has been changed from your question, you shouldn't need a getPreviousVersion(id) function in your database connector, but merely a function to get an element by id*/

 def getAllPreviousVersions(e: ElementModel): Future[Seq[ElementModel]] = {
    e.previousVersion match {
      case None => Future.successful(Seq(e))
      case Some(id) => getPreviousVersion(id).flatMap {
        previousVersionElement =>
          getAllPreviousVersions(previousVersionElement).map {
            //Properly preserves order !
            seq => previousVersionElement +: seq
          }
      }
    }
  }

 def getPreviousVersions(e: ElementModel) = {

    getAllPreviousVersions(e).map {

      //do something with the versions
      //Return something in the end
      ???
    }
  }
```